# BeautifulSoup use select multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

My problem is related to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47776460/format-html-code-with-python?answertab=active#tab-top).

I have following code:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

time = 0

html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.kramerav.com/de/Product/VM-2N").read()
html2 = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.kramerav.com/de/Product/SDIA-IN2-F16").read()
try:
    div = str(BeautifulSoup(html).select("div.large-image")[0])
    if(str(BeautifulSoup(html).select("div.large-image")[1]) != ""):
        div += str(BeautifulSoup(html).select("div.large-image")[1])
    time = time + 1
except IndexError:
    div = ""
    time = time + 1
finally:
    print(str(time) + div)
```

The site of the variable html has 2 div-classes named "large-image". The site of the variable html2 only has 1. 
With html the program works as intended. But if I switch to html2 the variable div is going to be completely empty.

I would like to save the 1 div-class rather than saving nothing. How could I archieve this?

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you after all the images available in those two pages in a single run?

Answer (score 1):

> the variable div is going to be completely empty.

That's because your error handler assigned it the empty string.

Please don't use subscripts, conditionals, and handlers in that way. It would be more natural to iterate over the results of select() with `for`, building up a result list (or string).

Also, you should create `soup = BeautifulSoup(html)` just once, as that can be a fairly expensive operation, since it carefully parses a potentially long web page. With that, you could build up a list of HTML fragments with:

```
    images = [image
              for image in soup.select('div.large-image')]
```

Or if for some reason you're not fond list comprehensions, you could equivalently write:

```
    images = []
    for image in soup.select('div.large-image'):
        images.append(image)
```

and then get the required html with `div = '\n'.join(images)`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I shortened it to `select = BeautifulSoup(html).select("div.large-image")`. Now I can use select[index]. 

But how do I use the for-loop?
`for i in select[i]:` Would be my guess, but I don't know what to do from there.

Comment: @dun you means `for item in select` ? `select` is list so use it as any other list.

Comment: Yes I meant something like that. Sorry, my programming skills are pretty low.   

When I use `for i in select:
div = str(i)` it only saves the second div in the String div. How could I save both?

Comment: concatenate `div += str(i)` inside `for i in select: div += str(i)`. Or inside `for` loop save directly in file. ie `for i in select: csv_writer.writerow([str(i)])`

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate all items inside `for` loop

```
    all_divs = soup.select("div.large-image")

    for item in all_divs:
        div += str(item)
        time += 1
```

or using `join()`

```
    time = len(all_divs)

    div = ''.join(str(item) for item in all_divs)
```

You can also write in file directly inside `for` loop and you get to row

```
    for item in all_divs:
        csv_writer.writerow( [str(item).strip()] )
        time += 1
```

Working example

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

div = ""
time = 0

f = open('output.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(f)

all_urls = [
  "https://www.kramerav.com/de/Product/VM-2N",
  "https://www.kramerav.com/de/Product/SDIA-IN2-F16",
]

for url in all_urls:
    print('url:', url)

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()

    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        all_divs = soup.select("div.large-image")

        for item in all_divs:
            div += str(item)
            time += 1

        # or     
        time = len(all_divs)
        div = ''.join(str(item) for item in all_divs)

        # or

        for item in all_divs:
            #div += str(item)
            #time += 1
            csv_writer.writerow( [time, str(item).strip()] )

    except IndexError as ex:
        print('Error:', ex)
        time += 1
    finally:
        print(time, div)

f.close()
```